# Gatsby build fails on 404 page and gtag plugin

Tags: gatsby, netlify, gatsby-plugin

my gatsby build keeps failing every-time on the 404 page and then on the gtag plugin. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

```
10:27:42 PM: error Truncated page data information for the failed page "/404/": {
10:27:42 PM:   "errors": {},
10:27:42 PM:   "path": "/404/",
10:27:42 PM:   "slicesMap": {},
10:27:42 PM:   "pageContext": {}
10:27:42 PM: }
10:27:42 PM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 7.088s
10:27:42 PM: error Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"
10:27:42 PM: 
10:27:42 PM:   37 |   var setComponents = pluginConfig.head ? setHeadComponents : setPostBodyComponents;
10:27:42 PM:   38 |   var renderHtml = function renderHtml() {
10:27:42 PM: > 39 |     return "\n      " + (excludeGtagPaths.length ? "window.excludeGtagPaths=[" + excludeGtagPaths.join(",") + "];" : "") + "\n      " + (typeof gtagConfig.anonymize_ip !== "undefined" && gtagConfig.anonymize_ip === true ? "function gaOptout(){document.cookie=disableStr+'=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;path=/',window[disableStr]=!0}var gaProperty='" + firstTrackingId + "',disableStr='ga-disable-'+gaProperty;document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr+'=true')>-1&&(window[disableStr]=!0);" : "") + "\n      if(" + (pluginConfig.respectDNT ? "!(navigator.doNotTrack == \"1\" || window.doNotTrack == \"1\")" : "true") + ") {\n        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\n        gtag('js', new Date());\n\n        " + pluginOptions.trackingIds.map(function (trackingId) {
10:27:42 PM:      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
10:27:42 PM:   40 |       return "gtag('config', '" + trackingId + "', " + JSON.stringify(gtagConfig) + ");";
10:27:42 PM:   41 |     }).join("") + "\n      }\n      ";
10:27:42 PM:   42 |   };
10:27:42 PM: 
10:27:42 PM:   WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') (  from plugin: gatsby-plugin-google-gtag)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to install `gatsby-plugin-gtag` and remove `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`